# dataTables initialization returning jQuery object, not API

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am initializing my table with DataTables.js

```
$('#clients').dataTable();
```

this is returning the jQuery DOM element, instead of the API.

How do I gain access to the API?

Comment: For the record, I am using DataTables 1.9.4 and jQuery UI 1.9.2

Answer (score 2):

*It is **only** in dataTables 1.10.x, using the constructor `.DataTable()`, that you receive an fully qualified API-object.*

In dataTables v 1.9.4 (versions below 1.10.x) the returned jQuery object is *extended* with the DataTables API methods.

When you have

```
var dataTable = $('#clients').dataTable();
```

you have direct access to the API through the variable `dataTable`, like `dataTable.fnFilter()`.

The following API methods are directly supported by a 1.9.x dataTables jQuery object :

```
fnAddData
fnAdjustColumnSizing
fnClearTable
fnClose
fnDeleteRow
fnDestroy
fnDraw
fnFilter
fnGetData
fnGetNodes
fnGetPosition
fnIsOpen
fnOpen
fnPageChange
fnSetColumnVis
fnSettings
fnSort
fnSortListener
fnUpdate
fnVersionCheck
```

demonstration -> **http://jsfiddle.net/L6rJk/**

The API in 1.10.x is vastly extended, and is backwards compatible. But most functions and API-references on the newly redesigned homepage http://datatables.net/ are targeting 1.10.x only! To view the old documentation, goto http://legacy.datatables.net/